# Local Wordpress Development Database Connection

Tags: database, wordpress, macos, xampp, local

I have my local development environment localhost set up to look to my 'user/sites/' folder. I'm working on a new project now using Wordpress, when I try and install it I get an error that says 'unable to establish database connection.' Everything I find online recommends using MAMP or XAMPP. I tried out XAMPP, still same problem. When  I look through the documentation, their localhost points to a folder inside XAMPP. How do I connect the two? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to check if you enable the service on XAMPP. Make sure that Apache and MySQL Database.

Example:
[image]

Next is check your credentials(Database Name, Username, and Password) this can be a factor that you got the error.